# Is there a way to specify date time format when importing excel to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am trying to follow a tutorial of SQL project on youtube and when I try to import my xlsx to MSSMS with the import export wizard, the resulting DateTime is off by at least couple hundred years or it will just be imported as null in the database. Anyone has the solution for this, I have tried to match the exact DateTime format in excel to match the format in database but still not working.

[Excel Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLGtb.png)

[Imported Data in microsoft sql server management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BINPp.png)

Comment: You can write "select" query for each data row ending with " union all" using Excel "concat" function. Then select and copy these query rows, and write insert query from this select subquery.

Comment: reformat the date format to 20220101 00:00:00  yyyymmdd hh:MM:ss